# SQL Server Diagram Tool - how to make connectors (relationships) glued to column names

Tags: database, ssms, diagram

Is there any way to force SQL Server (in management studio) diagram tool to AUTOMATICALLY show connections between exact columns of the tables and not just tables?

[image: see the attach picture]?[Diagram Tool-SSMS]